# Correct way to structure an HTML app

Tags: android, iphone, html, jquery-mobile, web-applications

I've previously made native apps but I'm considering making an HTML/JS app. I'm uncertain as to how these should be structured.

For example:

- Should the app just be a webview that points to my server, ie: www.example.com/webapp and have ALL the app files and resources there?
- Should ALL the app files be contained inside the executable?
- Something in between, like for example have big asset files (images, maybe libraries like jQuery) stored locally while the actual app gets pulled in from my server, as to always use the latest code.

This app in particular needs Internet access as it's only purpose really is to query a database of local offers, so in this case I'm not worried about providing offline access to any functionality.

Also, will Apple approve of any app that is just a webview pointing to a server, since I could totally change the functionality after it's approved?

Any other thing I should be aware of when creating HTML mobile apps, specially in regards to getting Apple approval?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple will aprove .ipa apps that are using just HTML and web languanges. However Apple has several requirements when submitting apps to the app store. These requirements sometimes make people who develope apps using HTML5 think their apps got rejected because it was in HTML5.

I would suggest coding in standard HTML5 [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), CSS and using JSON for your MySQL Databases. You can compile your app using [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) this way you can make it for many types of mobile devices or you can simply upload it to your server.

Comment: Will Apple allow just a web view that points to my server which serves my webapp?

Comment: @Rob Yes and No. One thing I hate about Apple is how to preach creativity and inovation yet they will reject an app for the way it looks. Here is a tip Google **how to make iTabBar** with HTML most of the time web apps that get rejected can easily be resubmitted after adding the iTabBar it shouldn't matter if the app is stored on the server or not

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) it uses WebView in Android and IOS.
Also check Phonegap based frameworks and plugins like:
[Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/)
[KendoUI and Icenium](http://www.kendoui.com/)
[Convertigo](http://www.convertigo.com/)
[Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/)

You can also use jQuery mobile with those tools.

Comment: The question is too general, all these sites has a great tutorials and videos.

Comment: I think this must be closed then.

Comment: Hi guys. I believe the question is ok... it's this answer that is general. I wasn't looking for a list of frameworks, that can easily be Googled. I'm interested in learning what is the best structure for mobile apps, as I explained in my question. Plus there are some very specific Apple related questions.

Comment: So you got a list of frameworks which support every feature you mentioned, only you know what is best for you.